# How to get selected rows using checkbox in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Hi i've a problem related to html.checkbox in my MVC application.

My scenario is:

I've a list(index view) page where i bind data from the database with a checkbox to select/deselect the item. when i click save button  i want to get selected rows to save those items back to db.

i used

```
1.  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="<%= item.recid %>" >  
    // I'm not getting value of chk2 in serverside 

2. <%= html.CheckBox("chk1")%>
    // i'm getting chk1 in serverside with value like 'true,false,true,false...'
```

in my model view iteration.

So how to do that in MVC application?

Comment: Can you give us some more of your code. What you are displaying in the view and the relevant code from your action?

Answer (score 7):

This is how I do it...

In the **view**, give all your checkboxes the same *name* and a unique *value*.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MyCheckboxes" value="<%= item.recid %>" >
```

In your **controller** action method, pass an IList with the name of the checkboxes.

```
public ActionResult MyActionMethod(IList<string> MyCheckboxes)
{
...
}
```

You'll receive in MyCheckboxes a list of the *values* of only those checkboxes that were selected.

Answer (score 1):

For 1), you need to specify a name on the input element.

You then need to match that name to a parameter on your Action Method.